# Upload in Alfresco Repository

Tags: rest, alfresco

I'm new to Alfresco. What i'm trying to do is to upload a file through REST API in a folder that i have created using Alfresco Web Administration Interface. I have a few problems:

1) I can see a set of folders, but how are them managed by Alfresco? As far as i know, those folders doesn't really exists physically, they are virtual. How does Alfresco manage the folders structure and files?

2) I have seen many examples on the _REST API use to upload a file. Anyway, the destination is set by something like this

```
workspace://SpacesStore/aae3b33fd-23d4-4091-ae64-44a8e332091341
```

I can't understand: What exactly is a SpaceStore? And, does the last-part-code refers to a specific folder? How can i get those codes relative to the folder i see in the Alfresco Web Admin Interface?

Comment: For 1) you will have to read http://wiki.alfresco.com/. 2) This is a NodeRef that identifies each node. Do you have a specific problem using the REST API?

Comment: Yes, i have no idea on how to get the NodeRef of a folder i'm viewing in the web admin interface

Comment: Are you using Share?

Comment: Yes i'm using share. Can you please suggest me the most relevant chapter on wiki regarding repository?

Comment: Get a training, these are basic stuff you need to know prior to developing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) I can see a set of folders, but how are them managed by Alfresco?
>   As far as i know, those folders doesn't really exists physically, they
>   are virtual. How does Alfresco manage the folders structure and files?

Alfresco is an implementation of the Java Content Repository (JCR), this means that all the contents are managed using a logic structure similar to a graph of nodes. Storing and manipolating content must be done using the repository API, that's why you don't see anything at a storage level.
Each content in Alfresco is a node connected to at least another node: the parent.

The storage of Alfresco is based on two components:

1. File system for storing binaries and search indexes
2. Database for storing the backup of metadata and associations

The way how Alfresco stores contents is not important for you because you typically want to access using the Alfresco API. You can create your own logic structure in the repository using any type of folders tree and content associations.

> 2) I have seen many examples on the _REST API use to upload a file.
>   Anyway, the destination is set by something like this
>   workspace://SpacesStore/aae3b33fd-23d4-4091-ae64-44a8e332091341 I
>   can't understand: What exactly is a SpaceStore? And, does the
>   last-part-code refers to a specific folder?

A repository typically consists of a set of JCR workspaces, the SpacesStore is one of the workspaces in Alfresco and it is the logic partition of contents in their latest version.

Alfresco also contains other workspaces:

1. userStore: contains person nodes
2. archiveStore: contains removed nodes
3. version2Store: contains the version history of nodes

> How can i get those codes relative to the folder i see in the Alfresco
>   Web Admin Interface?

That code is the node reference that is the unique identifier for each node in the repository and as you can see it consists of three parts:

workspace: the store protocol
SpacesStore: the store identifier
uuid: the UUID related to the node

The store reference consists of the store protocol appended with the store identifier and it is the identifier of the workspace where the node lives. The UUID specify the content inside the workspace.

These node references are the ID for nodes and you can see all these informations using the Node Browser inside the Alfresco Explorer | Administration Console trying to navigate your repository starting from the Company Home.

Hope this helps.

Comment: potevi scriverlo in italiano, ma grazie mille :D